# A custom delegate for an NSObject class that fires before leaving the view

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am working with an NSobject class and in that am editing a table, i need a delegate method that fires before leaving the view ,which asks for save or cancel..

Comment: And you want us to write it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIAlertView category that uses blocks

https://github.com/jivadevoe/UIAlertView-Blocks

This can help you avoid delegates, you can do all in one scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

i think that is the way to do that